# PHP strptime format bug?

Tags: php, formatting, strptime

I am wrestling with a php 5.2.6 problem. An api we use returns dates in this format DDMMYYYYHHMM. Exactly that format, fixed length, no delimiters. However, in my experimentation, this format seems to break strptime, which returns a false (fail) when I feed it a date in this format. It can reproduced, at least on my system, with this example:

```
$format = "%d%m%Y%H%M"; echo print_r(strptime(strftime($format,1225405967),$format),true);
```

If I add any character between the date and the time, it works, even a space. So, this DOES work:

```
$format = "%d%m%Y %H%M"; echo print_r(strptime(strftime($format,1225405967),$format),true);
```

Am I missing something obvious?

edit: further to this and owing to the results indicated by the comments, this seems to be platform specific. I can reproduce it on the Macs running OSX Leopard in the office but the Linux boxes parse it fine. I assume it is a bug or idiosyncrasy of the strptime in the underlying C library in the *nix of OSX.

Comment: What platform are you using?  I tried your example on PHP 5.2.6 (cli) Linux Kernel 2.6.9-55 and had two arrays output that looked exactly the same.

Comment: My dev platform is OSX Leopard and Apache2. Interesting results, thanks for the response.

Comment: This is looking more platform specific all the time. I can get it to work (both examples) on another server running yet another Linux distro. I'll keep searching for known bugs in the strptime in the C library shipped with Mac OSX. Seems that is where my problem lies.

Comment: Good Luck!  I don't have any Mac platforms around to test on, sorry.

Comment: I get the problem as you describe on Leopard using the stock PHP. My MAMP installation on the same box works fine though.

Answer (score 1):

This function is locale-dependent. Have you tried setting different locale? (see `setlocale()`)

Answer (score 1):

If you think the problem is on MacOS X and in the C library, then you could produce a test case to demonstrate it.  For example, I ran the code below on MacOS X 10.4.11 (PPC, G4, 32-bit), and got the output:

```
Now: 1225573977
Formatted (12): 011120082112
End: 0xBFFFF553 (Buffer: 0xBFFFF547)
Then: year = 2008, month = 11, day = 1, hour = 21, minute = 12
Reformatted (12): 011120082112
```

The code I used is:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    time_t now = time(0);
    struct tm *tm = gmtime(&now);
    char format[] = "%d%m%Y%H%M";
    char buffer1[64];
    char buffer2[64];
    size_t f_len = strftime(buffer1, sizeof(buffer1), format, tm);
    struct tm then;
    char *end = strptime(buffer1, format, &then);
    size_t p_len = strftime(buffer2, sizeof(buffer2), format, &then);

    printf("Now: %ld\n", (long)now);
    printf("Formatted (%lu): %s\n", (unsigned long)f_len, buffer1);
    printf("End: 0x%08lX (Buffer: 0x%08lX)\n", (unsigned long)end, (unsigned long)buffer1);
    printf("Then: year = %d, month = %d, day = %d, hour = %d, minute = %d\n",
            then.tm_year + 1900, then.tm_mon + 1, then.tm_mday, then.tm_hour, then.tm_min);
    printf("Reformatted (%lu): %s\n", (unsigned long)p_len, buffer2);

    return(0);
}
```

On the basis of what I see, there is no bug in strptime() in the version I'm using.  We can debate about the merits of the non-existent error checking, and of the casts versus C99 `<inttypes.h>` notations in the printing, but I think the code is accurate enough.  I used `gmtime()` instead of `localtime()`; I doubt if that was a factor in not reproducing the problem.

Maybe you should look at the PHP test suite?
Maybe you should split your rather complex expression into pieces to detect where the error occurs in PHP?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing obvious since both versions work fine in PHP 5.2.0. I can't readily check 5.2.6 at the moment, though. That will have to wait until I get home.

Comment: Tnanks for the reply. It seems it is platform specific. My dev platform of OSX Leopard and the strptime in the underlying C library seems to be the culprit. I cannot reproduce it on Linux boxes either but both the Macs in the office display the same behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

It's very likely that this is isolated to Macs only, as this hasn't even been implemented on Windows yet (although I've passed that suggestion along).

```
5.2.6
Fatal error: Call to undefined function strptime() in F:\htdocs\strptime.php on line 5
```

I would go ahead and submit a bug at [bugs.php.net](http://bugs.php.net/).

Answer (score 0):

I confirm:

```
    $p = strptime("09.02.2002", "%d.%m.%Y");
    var_dump($p);
```

Output:

array(9) {
  ["tm_sec"]=>
  int(0)
  ["tm_min"]=>
  int(0)
  ["tm_hour"]=>
  int(0)
  ["tm_mday"]=>
  int(9)
  ["tm_mon"]=>
  int(1)
  ["tm_year"]=>
  int(102)
  ["tm_wday"]=>
  int(0)
  ["tm_yday"]=>
  int(0)
  ["unparsed"]=>
  string(0) ""
}

OS X Leopard, PHP 5.3.2