# Check Valid date type

Tags: php, date, validation

may be this question had been asked, I've searched but still not confident about my problem..

my problem is checking valid date from string

```
$a='23-June-11'; //valid
$b='Normal String';//invalid
```

I want to convert $a and $b using strtotime()
before I do that, of course i want to validate whether $a or $b is a valid date format

From $a i can get 23, 11 using explode function, but how about 'June'?
using function above, 'June' is not numeric

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not let `strtotime()` do the validation?

It will return `false` if it's an invalid date.

Otherwise, you'd have to rebuild `strtotime()`'s functionality in order to do the validation - sounds like a futile (and big) exercise to me.

Comment: hmmm..do you mean validation like this?

`if(strtotime('somestring')){ //will return false`

Comment: There is a small issue with `strtotime`. It will validate dates such as "+1 hour" and "last day of the month".

Comment: strtotime cannot be used to validate a date. how would it work on something like 12-12-2012. Also its not possible to specify a format with strtotime.

Comment: @Silver well, it worked for the OP's requirement... if you have a better, more universal suggestion, feel free to post it. If it's good, you'll have my upvote

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to `strtotime` which will accept relative dates such as "yesterday", "last date of next month" and even "-1 year", I propose using [`strptime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strptime.php). It's used to parse a date string according to a format that you specify.

In your case, you'd want `strptime($date, '%d-%B-%y')`.

Example:

```
<?php

// Set the locale as en_US to make sure that strptime uses English month names.
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'en_US');

$dates = array(
  '23-June-11',
  'Normal String'
);

foreach ( $dates as $date )
{
  if ( strptime($date, '%d-%B-%y') )
  {
    echo $date . ' is a valid date' . PHP_EOL;
  }
  else
  {
    echo $date . ' is an invalid date' . PHP_EOL;
  }
}
```

Output:

```
23-June-11 is a valid date
Normal String is an invalid date
```

Comment: Very nice and simple solution

Comment: According to
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/254244/php-strptime-format-bug

this function is not perfect, i can't use it too..

Note: This function is not implemented on Windows platforms. (From php.net)

I use windows paltform

Comment: @yukou - That's because as the the `strptime` documentation says, it's locale dependant. If you add `setlocale(LC_TIME, 'en_US');` at the top, it'll force the function to use English month names as otherwise, it'll use the system default which may be in another language.

Comment: strptime will report dates like 30-02-2012 correct. it has other limitations too. therefore it is not a full proof method to validate a date